# How to write good conversion from string to enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have the following class that converts a string to an enum. But I feel this is somehow not the right way to do things with enums. How could I do better?

Example (that does not make sense, but illustrates my problem):

```
enum LetterType {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;

    public static LetterType fromValue(String v) {
        if (v.equals("A") || v.equals("B")) {
            return ONE;
        } else if (v.equals("C") {
            return TWO;
        } else if (v.equals("D") {
            return THREE;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered maintaining a `Map<String, LetterType>`?

Comment: You might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com. I don't feel this question is appropriate for SO as it will generate a lot of opinion-based answers, relating to which piece of code is more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
enum LetterType {
ONE, TWO, THREE;

private static Map<String, LetterType> stringValues;
static {
    stringValues = new HashMap<>();
    stringValues.put("A", ONE);
    stringValues.put("B", ONE);
    stringValues.put("C", TWO);
    stringValues.put("D", THREE);
}

public static LetterType fromValue(String v) {
    return stringValues.get(v);
}
```

}

Comment: N.B. the map should be immutable or at least a `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`.

Comment: It's a private map, I hope nobody will modify it in the enum itself!

Answer (score 0):

There is going to have to be some logic that determines what value maps to which enum.  In C you could've done some unreadable trick with casting the string to its ASCII code and using some formula to determine a mapping -- note that I don't condone that practice. In Java you're going to have to do something more readable and one way or another, you're going to need to dictate which value maps to which enum.

You could use a `Map<String, enum_type>` that you fill with mappings to condense your logic, or you could use an if/else block.  If you wanted to have a direct String-->Enum where the enum's name is the same as the String's value, you could use `enumVariable.valueOf("StringGoesHere")` but your example doesn't seem to suggest that ordering.